# Clarifying EMF for a moving magnet

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

Lots of textbooks quote the formula $\mathcal{E} = \oint(\textbf{v}\times\textbf{B})\cdot{\rm d}\textbf{l}$ for the EMF induced along a circuit moving at velocity $\textbf{v}$ inside a stationary magnetic field $\textbf{B}$.

But then, what if instead the circuit was stationary, and the field was moving with velocity $\textbf{u}$ (e.g. a magnet moving through a coil)? I haven't found anywhere discussing this scenario.

Assuming the same relative motion occurs (i.e. if in the first case the circuit was moving to the left, in the second case the magnet moves to the right), isn't $\textbf{u} = -\textbf{v}$? And as such the EMF is $\mathcal{E} = -\oint(\textbf{u}\times\textbf{B})\cdot{\rm d}\textbf{l}$?

Answer (score 0):

When you have stationary conductors inside of varying magnetic fields, then it is best to use the other form of Faraday's law $$\mathcal E=-\frac{\text d\Phi_B}{\text dt}$$

where $\Phi_B=\iint\mathbf B\cdot\text d\mathbf a$ is the magnetic flux through the closed circuit loop.

The equation you propose is also true... but what you are essentially doing is "Let's assume the circuit is stationary, but then move to the frame where the circuit is moving." There is nothing wrong with this at all, but it seems to go against what you are really asking about here.

Comment: How then can I represent this equation in terms of the magnetic field of the magnet, $\textbf{B}$, and it's velocity, $\textbf{u}$?

Comment: @jonnybolton16 $\Phi_B=\iint\mathbf B\cdot\text d\mathbf a$, so the time derivative of this quantity will necessarily depend on the field of the magnet and the velocity of the magnet. For a simpler toy example you can do by hand, imagine a square loop of wire that enters a region of constant magnetic field. In the frame of the loop, the magnetic field is moving across the loop at some velocity. You should be able to work out the change in magnetic flux and see that it depends on both the field and the velocity of the field (in the frame of the loop).

Comment: Fundamentally, all I know is that I have $\textbf{B}$ moving at some velocity. Even though it's moving, it doesn't depend on $t$ itself. So I'm not sure what to do with $-d/dt \iint \textbf{B}\cdot{\rm d}\textbf{a}$

Comment: @jonnybolton16 Even if $\mathbf B$ has no time dependency in one frame it doesn't mean $\mathbf B$ is constant in time in all frames. If the field is moving relative to the loop then it has to have some sort of time dependency in the frame of the loop, right? If not, then how could you say it is moving? If I need to update my answer with an example please let me know.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. So my question now is, from the frame of the stationary coil, what is $\textbf{B}(\textbf{x},t)$ if the magnet is moving towards the coil with velocity $\textbf{u}$ and has a field from it's own frame of $\textbf{B}(\textbf{x})$?

Comment: @jonnybolton16 It would just be $\mathbf B(\mathbf x_0+\mathbf ut)$, since $\mathbf x_0+\mathbf ut$ is how the position would change over time for constant velocity motion.

Comment: What if the velocity depents on time? Sorry, I should have explicitly said that earlier

Answer (score 0):

In the end, you expect the force to be independent of the **inertial** frame of reference you use, so your relativist intuition is right, except from $\mathbf u = - \mathbf v$.

When the circuit moves with constant velocity, you can consider a change of reference via a Lorentz transformation that puts you in the frame of reference of the circuit. There the circuit is of course stationary. When you transform the electromagnetic tensor, you will find that the magnetic component of the field gives rise to an electric component that contributes to the EMF.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by electromagnetic tensor...